Handling Multiple Operations on DataFrame Columns with Polars
I'm trying to select all columns of a DataFrame and perform multiple operations on each column using Polars. For example, I discovered that I can use the following code to count non-null values in each column:
df.select(pl.col("*").is_not_null().sum()

However, when I attempt to concatenate multiple operations like this:
(
    df
    .select(
        pl.col("*").is_not_null().sum().alias("foo"),
        pl.col("*").is_null().sum().alias("bar")
    )
)

I encounter a Duplicated Error. This seems to happen because Polars tries to perform the operations but ends up using the same column names, which causes the duplication issue.
To work around this, I'm currently using the following approach:
a = (
    df
    .select(
        pl.col("*").is_null().sum(),

    )
    .transpose(include_header=True)
    .rename(
        {"column_0" : "null_count"}
    )
)

b = (
    df
    .select(
        pl.col("*").is_not_null().sum(),

    )
    .transpose(include_header=True)
    .rename(
        {"column_0" : "not_null_count"}
    )
)

a.join(b, how="left", on="column")

My goal is to generate an output that looks like this:
shape: (8, 3)
┌─────────────┬────────────┬────────────────┐
│ column      ┆ null_count ┆ not_null_count │
│ ---         ┆ ---        ┆ ---            │
│ str         ┆ u32        ┆ u32            │
╞═════════════╪════════════╪════════════════╡
│ InvoiceNo   ┆ 0          ┆ 541909         │
│ StockCode   ┆ 0          ┆ 541909         │
│ Description ┆ 1454       ┆ 540455         │
│ Quantity    ┆ 0          ┆ 541909         │
│ InvoiceDate ┆ 0          ┆ 541909         │
│ UnitPrice   ┆ 0          ┆ 541909         │
│ CustomerID  ┆ 135080     ┆ 406829         │
│ Country     ┆ 0          ┆ 541909         │
└─────────────┴────────────┴────────────────┘


df.describe() may be of interest.

I'm aware of the .describe()  method, but i would like to do another operations and use it to plot later.

Let's use a simple test input
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "InvoiceNo": [1,2,3],
    "StockCode": [1,None,3],
    "Description": [None,None,6]
})

To get your desired output, you can use

unpivot() to transpose the DataFrame.
Also, you don't really need to calculate both values, as soon as you calculated count of null values, you can use len(df) - null_count to calculate not_null_count.

(
    df
    .select(pl.all().is_null().sum())
    .unpivot(variable_name="column", value_name="null_count")
    .with_columns(not_null_count = len(df) - pl.col.null_count)
)

┌──────────────┬────────────┬────────────────┐
│ column       ┆ null_count ┆ not_null_count │
│ ---          ┆ ---        ┆ ---            │
│ str          ┆ u32        ┆ u32            │
╞══════════════╪════════════╪════════════════╡
│ InvoiceNo    ┆ 0          ┆ 3              │
│ StockCode    ┆ 1          ┆ 2              │
│ Description  ┆ 2          ┆ 1              │
└──────────────┴────────────┴────────────────┘

And if you want your result in non-unpivoted shape (as in, one row an multiple columns), you can use .name.suffix():
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.all().is_null().sum().name.suffix("_is_null"),
        pl.all().is_not_null().sum().name.suffix("_is_not_null")
    )
)

┌───────────┬───────────┬──────────────┬───────────────┬───┬──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┐
│ InvoiceNo ┆ StockCode ┆ Description  ┆ InvoiceNo_is_ ┆ … ┆ Description  ┆ InvoiceNo_is ┆ StockCode_is ┆ Description  │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---          ┆ null          ┆   ┆ _is_null     ┆ _not_null    ┆ _not_null    ┆ _is_not_null │
│ i64       ┆ i64       ┆ i64          ┆ ---           ┆   ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---          │
│           ┆           ┆              ┆ u32           ┆   ┆ u32          ┆ u32          ┆ u32          ┆ u32          │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪══════════════╪═══════════════╪═══╪══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╡
│ 1         ┆ 1         ┆ null         ┆ 0             ┆ … ┆ 2            ┆ 3            ┆ 2            ┆ 1            │
│ 2         ┆ null      ┆ null         ┆ 0             ┆ … ┆ 2            ┆ 3            ┆ 2            ┆ 1            │
│ 3         ┆ 3         ┆ 6            ┆ 0             ┆ … ┆ 2            ┆ 3            ┆ 2            ┆ 1            │
└───────────┴───────────┴──────────────┴───────────────┴───┴──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┘

And if you want several different aggregates, you can do unpivot() first:
(
    df
    .unpivot(variable_name="column")
    .group_by("column")
    .agg(
        not_null_count = pl.col.value.is_not_null().sum(),
        mean = pl.col.value.mean()
    )
)

┌─────────────┬────────────────┬──────┐
│ column      ┆ not_null_count ┆ mean │
│ ---         ┆ ---            ┆ ---  │
│ str         ┆ u32            ┆ f64  │
╞═════════════╪════════════════╪══════╡
│ StockCode   ┆ 2              ┆ 2.0  │
│ InvoiceNo   ┆ 3              ┆ 2.0  │
│ Description ┆ 1              ┆ 6.0  │
└─────────────┴────────────────┴──────┘


Is there a particular advantage of using unpivot rather than transpose as I did in my answer?

honestly, not sure, but there's a This is a very expensive operation. Perhaps you can do it differently. comment in the documentation

OK, maybe when all column types are different, which shouldn't be the case here. Good to know. Side comment, your edit to add the name.suffix now makes our answers very similar.

Yep I was adding it as an addition to show why OP original attempt was failing.

It's pretty Close @RomanPekar , But what about if i'm tryng to get not_nulls() and mean() for example?  How can i unpivot the new suffixes keeping the originals columns name

@Simon see updated answer

A lot of workarounds! Thanks a lot for your time @RomanPekar

In your second code, all columns are combined, you could thus give them a suffix with name.suffix if you want to keep all without duplicated names:
(
    df
    .select(
        pl.col("*").is_not_null().sum().name.suffix('_not_null'),
        pl.col("*").is_null().sum().name.suffix('_null')
    )
)

Output:
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬──────────┐
│ InvoiceNo ┆ StockCode ┆ Descripti ┆ Quantity_ ┆ … ┆ InvoiceDa ┆ UnitPrice ┆ CustomerI ┆ Country_ │
│ _not_null ┆ _not_null ┆ on_not_nu ┆ not_null  ┆   ┆ te_null   ┆ _null     ┆ D_null    ┆ null     │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ll        ┆ ---       ┆   ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---      │
│ u32       ┆ u32       ┆ ---       ┆ u32       ┆   ┆ u32       ┆ u32       ┆ u32       ┆ u32      │
│           ┆           ┆ u32       ┆           ┆   ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆          │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪══════════╡
│ 90        ┆ 88        ┆ 90        ┆ 87        ┆ … ┆ 14        ┆ 8         ┆ 9         ┆ 8        │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴──────────┘

Now, given your example, it might not make much sense to count all null AND all non-nulls, since the sum of the two is equal to the DataFrame's length.
You might want to compute one, transpose, then compute the second from the original length:
(df.select(pl.col('*').is_null().sum())
   .transpose(include_header=True, column_names=['null_count'])
   .with_columns(not_null_count=len(df)-pl.col('null_count'))
)

Example output:
┌─────────────┬────────────┬────────────────┐
│ column      ┆ null_count ┆ not_null_count │
│ ---         ┆ ---        ┆ ---            │
│ str         ┆ u32        ┆ u32            │
╞═════════════╪════════════╪════════════════╡
│ InvoiceNo   ┆ 10         ┆ 90             │
│ StockCode   ┆ 12         ┆ 88             │
│ Description ┆ 10         ┆ 90             │
│ Quantity    ┆ 13         ┆ 87             │
│ InvoiceDate ┆ 14         ┆ 86             │
│ UnitPrice   ┆ 8          ┆ 92             │
│ CustomerID  ┆ 9          ┆ 91             │
│ Country     ┆ 8          ┆ 92             │
└─────────────┴────────────┴────────────────┘

